# Any tool for automatically splitting a multi-page Visio file into multiple single-page Visio files?

Tags: microsoft-visio

I have a Visio file which has *tons* of pages (or tabs) in it, each having a different separate model. I need to make multiple Visio files out of this one file, such that each generated Visio file only contains one page from this main file .. If I do this manually, it will take a lot of time as there are like over even a 100 pages maybe ... So I'm looking for some automated solution ..

Any ideas ?

Comment: [Visio Super Utilities](http://www.paulherber.co.uk/visio-utilities/) by [Paul Herber](https://superuser.com/users/326075/paul-herber) also can do it !

Comment: @Ahmad Could you please answer this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1341399/how-to-add-values-to-the-x-axis-and-y-axis-of-a-cartesian-coordinates-in-visio Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a command-line tool called ""Visio Export Pages to Docs"" that exports pages from a Visio doc.

See: https://github.com/saveenr/Visio-Export-Pages-To-Docs

Usage:

```
VisioExportPagestoDocs.exe input.vsd
```

It will create a single output document for each page. The output documents will be placed in the same folder as the input document.